# list data from text file with php

Tags: php, html

I am using a text file as a database. This code only shows the row by the id I select. I want it to show everything from the text file.

```
<?php
$lines = file('database.txt');
$data = array();
$id = 1;

for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++){
if($lines[$i] == $id){
    $data[0] = $lines[$i];
    $data[1] = $lines[$i+1];
    $data[2] = $lines[$i+2];
    $data[3] = $lines[$i+3];
}
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>



<div class="box1">
   <h1><?= $data[1]; ?></h1>   
   <img src="<?= $data[2]; ?>">
    <p>
    <?= $data[3]; ?>
   </p> 
   <br />
   <a href="<?= $data[4]; ?>">Click  here!</a>
</div>

<div class="box1">
   <h1><?= $data[1]; ?></h1>   
   <img src="<?= $data[2]; ?>">
    <p>
    <?= $data[3]; ?>
   </p> 
   <br />
   <a href="<?= $data[4]; ?>">Click  here!</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my database file

```
    1
    Name
    Image
    My text
    Link
    -------
    2
    Name1
    Image1
    Text1
    Link1
    -------
    3
    Name3
    Image3
    Text3
    Link3
    -------
```

Comment: Why do you have that first for() loop? It's pointless. you could just have `if (isset($lines[$id])) { $data[0] = $lines[$id]; $data[1] = $lines[id+1]; etc...}`

Comment: If you're going to use text files as a db, why not `json_encode` them for easier access to the objects by later using `json_decode`? Perhaps something to look into.

Comment: the problem is with your text file. Also make sure short tags are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to answer your question
I don't know if you want to display *everything* at once, or just a table of contents type of deal, so here goes the former and I will edit my post if you need the latter

EDITED: added `trim` in the `if` clause to build the array properly and in the print function to eliminate new-lines.

a. show everything

```
<?php
$lines = file('database.txt');

$i=0;
foreach ($lines as $line){
    if (trim($line)!="-------") $data[$i][]=$line;
    else $i++;
}

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
foreach ($data as $key=>$val) {
    print '<div class="box'.$key.'">
    <h1>'.trim($val[1]).'</h1>
    <img src="'.trim($val[2]).'">
    <p>'.trim($val[3]).'</p> 
    <br />
    <a href="'.trim($val[4]).'">Click  here!</a>
    </div>';
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Next I suggest you store your information in CSV format, like this:

```
Name,Image,Text,Link
Bob,/home/images/bob.jpg,"some text",http://bob.example.com
Alice,/home/images/alice.png,"alice is wonderfull",http://alice.org
```

Then you can easily parse the csv file using `fgetcsv` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Hi Alex, yes I want to show everythingm, I tried your code... it's only show 1 box :(

Comment: take a look again, i have missed a closing bracket for the first foreach loop, maybe it was that

Comment: can you try run it on your pc?

Comment: edited the answer, also tested myself, it will display correctly, the mistake was in the `if` clause comparing the separators with the values from the file, I added the `trim` function to remove new-lines

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating things. This is the skeleton of all you'd need to do:

```
<body>

blah blahblah
<?php 
$data = file('database.txt');
foreach($data as $line) {
    echo $line[0];
}
?>

</html>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = file('database.txt');
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
   print_r($data[$i]); 
}
```